# Date value of a particular time in java

Tags: java, android, date

i want to take the date value of a particular time. in my application i just want to take the date value of '8 AM' in everyday.i just want to make a comparison in my app,like current time greater than '8 am'or not. for that i need to get long value of 8 AM in each day can anybody help me how to obtain this

Comment: Have you even looked at the Calendar class?

Comment: Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), always.

Comment: @John3136 yes ofcourse,in which i hve got to take current time, and converting a date format to date value. but not having any idea about how to get the date value of a particular time in each day

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "date value of '8 AM' in everyday"? If you know the date and time of "everyday" it wouldn't matter what the time is - all you need to do is extract the date alone.

Comment: @ADTC i just want to make a comparison in my app,like current time greater than '8 am'. for that i need to get long value of 8 AM in each day.

Comment: You may be interested in the `before` and `after` methods of `Calendar`. Basically, get two instances of time now, set the first instance to 8 AM (example in _earcam_'s answer), check if second instance is `after` first instance (it returns true/false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use Joda time / JSR310, then this should suffice.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class EightAm {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        }

    }
}
```

Prints 100 days' dates at 8AM, from today